# emberjs - how to mark active menu item using router infrastructure

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm trying to create navigation tabs (taken from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs)):

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

The active tab is marked with `class="active"`.

There is great example of static navbar and Router/Outlet feature at http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/pfbva/, but
I can't understand how to create a dynamic navbar/menu/tab view.

As far as I understand, it is possible to use class bindings in each menu item:

```js
 classNameBindings: ['isActive:active']
```

But where is the right place to switch isActive attributes ?

Comment: FYI: In the new router, `{{linkTo}}` provides this behavior automatically -- http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're using Ember >= 1.11, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/14501021/65542 below is the correct answer.

---

I would create a `NavigationView`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/z8ssG/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {{#view view.NavItemView item="home" }}
            <a {{action gotoHome}} >Home</a>
        {{/view}}
        {{#view view.NavItemView item="profiles" }}
            <a {{action gotoProfiles}} >Profiles</a>
        {{/view}}
        {{#view view.NavItemView item="messages" }}
            <a {{action gotoMessages}} >Messages</a>
        {{/view}}        
    </ul>
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.NavigationView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'navigation',
    selectedBinding: 'controller.selected',
    NavItemView: Ember.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        classNameBindings: 'isActive:active'.w(),
        isActive: function() {
            return this.get('item') === this.get('parentView.selected');
        }.property('item', 'parentView.selected').cacheable()
    })
});
```

And inside your route's `connectOutlets` you have to set the current navigation item via `router.set('navigationController.selected', 'home');` ...

---

Also take a look at the [ember-bootstrap](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap) repository, which wraps this and more features of Bootstrap inside Ember.js

Comment: can you update your answer to reflect changes in the new router? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328295/how-do-i-bind-to-the-active-class-of-a-link-using-the-new-ember-router.

Comment: what if you want the tabs to change without the url changing? (while also still using the router to get to the tabs, which are at say `/wizards/:wizard_id/edit` and there are 3 steps to edit in the wizard which you don't want to change the url.)

Comment: FWIW, I updated pangratz's example as illustrated with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/ydn9r/)

Comment: @bazzel: Unfortunately this is not working any more.

Comment: There should be better way that is not interresting, I have often to connect route logic to present logic. That is a bad way

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer anymore, as this won`t work for any recent ember version. I tried the summarize the working solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38634312/5556104

Answer (score 154):

Ember 1.11+:

```
{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li"}}
  <a href="{{view.href}}">Dashboard</a>
{{/link-to}}
```

Ember < 1.11 (`bind-attr` required):

```
{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li"}}
  <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Dashboard</a>
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer. I just spent 10 minutes trying to get a `bindAttr` on an <li> tag to reference the view.href by name until I found this and realized I had it all backwards.

Comment: @jonnii Agree, I've posted a full solution below combining the two pieces.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to do it

Comment: The problem is that this approach doesn't work with a nested menu

Comment: I guess with a nested menu, you'll need some specific component to handle it for you. Anyway this is the cleanest and easiest way to do it in the context of the original question.

Comment: Definitely the best answer I found out of the group.

Comment: This is definately the most easiest way to do it! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Just adding my support. A much better answer.

Comment: How exactly is the poor soul who comes across my code after I've inserted this oddity supposed to know that it will insert an 'active' class in the li? Very unclear.

Comment: You'll want to explicitly style your cursor to be a pointer when over the link element: `a {cursor: pointer;}`

See http://marceldegraaf.net/2013/05/17/ember-js-and-bootstrap-navbar-mark-li-active.html

Comment: AFAIK this solution will not work anymore as `href` wont be generated for a non `a` tags: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/tagname-and-html-best-practices/4260/3

Comment: This sort of works but the href for <a> tag does not work so command + click won't open in new tabs

Answer (score 17):

Some of the above suggestions are still valid for twitter bootstrap case. You can also try something like this

```
{{#link-to 'dashboard' tagName='li'}} 
  {{#link-to 'dashboard'}}Link Title{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

1. The `link-to` with `li` tagName applies the active class to the li
2. The inner `link-to` would be a `anchor` element which gives you `Open in New Tab` functionality when right-clicked

Comment: This is what we do, ideal for TWBS tabs

Answer (score 10):

Recently an Ember-cli addon came available to just do this. It is called [ember-cli-active-link-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-active-link-wrapper).

Install: `ember install ember-cli-active-link-wrapper`

You can use it like this:

```
{{#active-link}}
  {{link-to "Index" "index"}}
{{/active-link}}
```

which results in:

```
<li class='active'>
    <a href="/" class='active'>Index</a>
</li>
```

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer.  All the higher-upvoted ones are broken in modern Ember or otherwise unmaintainable.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old post, but here are updates for **Ember 2.4.0**

For creating links you can write

```
{{#link-to 'photoGallery'}}
  Great Hamster Photos
{{/link-to}}
```

or

```
{{link-to 'Great Hamster Photos' 'photoGallery'}}
```

Ember will automatically set class to active when current route matches link's route (in this example `photoGallery`).

If you want to control 'active' class on other routes as well, you can do it by setting `current-when` attribute.

```
{{#link-to 'photoGallery' current-when='photoGallery photoPreview'}}
  Great Hamster Photos
{{/link-to}}
```

This link will have `active` class on both `photoGallery` and `photoPreview` routes.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.4.0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/components/link-to.js#L140

Answer (score 4):

Handlebars

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>{{#linkTo "index"}}Index{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("about");
});
```

It will add active class automatically based on route.
Note: It is tested using ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js

Comment: This works, the only issue I'm having is that it doesn't set the default on my root link. I render my index template to my 'Intro' controller, but this doesn't set the class on the link. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the isActive method into something like this:

```
isActive: function() {
    return App.getPath('router.currentState.path') === "root.firms";
}.property("App.router.currentState"),
```

or

```
isActive: function() {
    return this.get('controller.target.currentState.path') === "root.firms";
}.property("controller.target.currentState"),
```

Answer (score 3):

I see this question is quite old, but if you upgraded Ember.js to the RC3 you can use `tagName` property, like:

```
{{#link-to messages tagName="li"}}Messages{{/link-to}}
```

Here is the API - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkView.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's very dynamic but try to see solution at http://codebrief.com/2012/07/anatomy-of-an-ember-dot-js-app-part-i-redux-routing-and-outlets/
The main idea is to check state of your app

**JavaScript:**

```
function stateFlag(name) {
  return Ember.computed(function() {
    var state = App.router.currentState;
    while(state) {
      if(state.name === name) return true;
      state = state.get('parentState');
    }
    return false;
  }).property('App.router.currentState');
}

ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend({
    isHome: stateFlag('home'),
    isSections: stateFlag('sections'),
    isItems: stateFlag('items')
  })
```

**Handlebars:**

```
<li class="home" {{bindAttr class="isHome:active"}}>
</li>
<li class="sections" {{bindAttr class="isSections:active"}}>
</li>
<li class="items" {{bindAttr class="isItems:active"}}>
</li>
```

**Update:**
pangratz's solution looks prettier

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full working solution:

View:

```
App.NavView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function() {
    return this.get('childViews.firstObject.active');
  }.property()
});
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in controller}}
  {{#view App.NavView}}
  {{#linkTo "item" item tagName="li"}}
      <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>
        {{ item.name }}
      </a>
  {{/linkTo}}
  {{/view}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with v0.8.0 [ember-bootstrap](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/) supports navs, including handling the active state correctly. And that without any link-to/tagName kind of hacks:

```
{{#bs-nav type="pills"}}
   {{#bs-nav-item}}
      {{#link-to "foo"}}Foo{{/link-to}}
   {{/bs-nav-item}}
   {{#bs-nav-item}}
     {{#link-to "bar"}}Bar{{/link-to}}
   {{/bs-nav-item}}
 {{/bs-nav}}
```

See http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/api/classes/Components.Nav.html

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the proposed solutions here do not work for any recent Ember version (e.g. views being deprecated). Moreover just using the `link-to` helper will not solve the issue, as bootstrap expects the `active` class to be present on the `<li>` not the `<a>`!

So I will try to summarize the solutions that do in fact work as of now:

#### use [ember-cli-active-link-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-active-link-wrapper)

The addon provides a component for this special use case:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  {{#active-link}}
    {{#link-to "foo"}}Foo{{/link-to}}
  {{/active-link}}
  {{#active-link}}
    {{#link-to "bar"}}Bar{{/link-to}}
  {{/active-link}}
</ul>
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939821/5556104

#### use [ember-bootstrap](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/)

[ember-bootstrap](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/) provides many components that integrate bootstrap functionality into your ember app, amongst them the nav components:

```
{{#bs-nav type="tabs"}}
   {{#bs-nav-item}}
      {{#link-to "foo"}}Foo{{/link-to}}
   {{/bs-nav-item}}
   {{#bs-nav-item}}
      {{#link-to "bar"}}Bar{{/link-to}}
   {{/bs-nav-item}}
 {{/bs-nav}}
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38279975/5556104

#### link-to Hack

Somewhat hacky, but should work without any additional addon:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  {{#link-to "foo" tagName="li"}} 
    {{#link-to "foo"}}Foo{{/link-to}}
  {{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to "bar" tagName="li"}} 
    {{#link-to "bar"}}Bar{{/link-to}}
  {{/link-to}}
</ul>
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966652/5556104

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later want to change the naming of your states or whatever you have to go through the code AND the view as well, also adding a function to transitionTo every route seems not desirable. 
My approach is a bit more programmatic and modularized:

```
# Parent View-Tamplate, holding the navbar DOM elements
App.NavView = Ember.View.extend( 
  controller: App.NavArrayController
  templateName: "ember-nav"
)
# We push NavItems into this array
App.NavArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.create(
  content: Ember.A([])
)
# NavItem has two settable properties and 
# an programmatic active state depending on the router
App.NavItem = Ember.Object.extend(
  title: ''
  goto: null    # <=this is the name of the state we want to go to!
  active: (->
    if App.router.currentState.name == @.get "goto"
      true
    else
      false
  ).property('App.router.currentState.name').cacheable()
)
# the actual NavElement which gets the class="active" if the 
# property "active" is true, plus a on-click binding to
# make the Router transition to this state
App.NavItemView = Ember.View.extend(
 tagName: "li"
  classNameBindings: ["active"]
  click: ->
    App.router.transitionTo(@get('goto'))
    false
)
```

nav-view.hbs (for twitter-bootstrap-style navs)

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    {{#each App.NavArrayController}}
      {{#view App.NavItemView classBinding="active" gotoBinding="goto"}}
        <a href="#" {{bindAttr data-goto="goto"}}> {{title}}</a>
      {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

This way, I can just create and mess around with my routes in the Router, 
and keep the Nav-Definitions side-by-side:

```
# put this somewhere close to the Router 
App.NavArrayController.pushObjects(
  [
    App.NavItem.create(
      title: 'Home'
      goto: 'home'
    ),
    App.NavItem.create(
      title: 'Chat'
      goto: 'chat'
    ),
    App.NavItem.create(
      title: 'Test'
      goto: 'test'
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

baijum's answer above is mostly correct however in the latest versions of Ember the "bind-attr" is deprecated. Here is the new way to write it:

```
{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li"}}
    <a href="{{view.href}}">Dashboard</a>
{{/link-to}}
```

As you can see, it's even easier and kind of works like magic..

Answer (score 0):

Like other people said, using `{{#link-to}}` to link to an existing `route`, when that route is current URL, `{{#link-to}}` will automatically add `active` to its CSS classes.

See [Ember issue 4387](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4387)