# emberjs router @pangratz example class active

Tags: ember.js, router

@pangratz give a answer in [emberjs - how to mark active menu item using router infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628489/emberjs-how-to-mark-active-menu-item-using-router-infrastructure)

The question is why when i change `{{outlet "navigation"}}` to `{{view App.NavigationView}}`, `NavigationView.selected` is undefined?

Comment: I think you can remove this question, as it's really related to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760949/emberjs-router-class-active. I will answer shortly here. Navigation.selected is undefined, because without using outlet (and so no go through connectOutlet), the controller's selected property is not set, and so, the binding not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using {{view App.NavigationView controllerBinding="App.router.navigationController"}} should make your code working. Thanks to this question: [connectOutlets from root state called before initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768294/connectoutlets-from-root-state-called-before-initialization)