# connectOutlets from root state called before initialization?

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/89S5p/

In root's connectOutlets, the `App` still seems un`.initialize()`d. Is connectOutlets not intended to be used with the root state? (And why?)

If I need something every time the page is loaded (such as in pangratz's NavigationView here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629977/363073), then I will need to have an all-inclusive root.index state like he does?

Comment: I think this discussion https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/941 will be usefull :)

Comment: @sly7_7 Thank you! Going to use `{{view App.NavigationView controllerBinding="App.router.navigationController"}}`
instead of `{{outlet "navigation"}}` based on trek's alternative from that discussion: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/941#issuecomment-6848712

Comment: cool :), I think this is an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767161/emberjs-router-pangratz-example-class-active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by sly7_7, this is still an open question -- apparently the functionality is considered desirable but seems to require an undesirable hack.
http://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/941

For now, either have all your routes in a subroute such as root.index, or manually bind the controller rather than using the outlet helper (e.g. `{{view App.NavigationView controllerBinding="App.router.navigationController"}}`).