# Ember.js Connect outlets before any route loads

Tags: ember.js

I have an application with 3 routes:

```
"/"
"/one"
"/two"
```

I want to connect outlets like `header` and `footer` on the `applicationView` before any of them load.

Since ember can only navigate to leaf nodes, I can't nest `/one` and `two` under `/` and still be able to navigate to `/`

This means that I would have to repeat the `connectOutlets` code for all 3 routes individually to hook up the `header` and `footer`.

I can't use `connectOutlets` on the `root` property of the Router as the `applicationController` is not ready yet.

How do I connect outlets on the `applicationView` when my application first loads before any routes are executed?

Comment: Something tells me you want to create a layout view for your app

Comment: Sorry, I may have answered your question too soon. Can you explain why your applicationController isn't ready in the root route?

Comment: @dmzza http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768294/connectoutlets-from-root-state-called-before-initialization

Comment: @pauldechov Thanks. I've always used what I edited below because someone else gave me that tip, now I know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use connectOutlets in non-leaf routes, and as the router traverses those routes to a leaf route, it will run those connectOutlets. To solve your other problem (routing to '/') it is a good practice to have an index route ('/') in any non-leaf route.

**Edit:** Since we've confirmed that applicationController is undefined in the root route, simply putting everything in a child of the root route seems to solve that problem, and it doesn't change the functionality of the router.

```js
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/',
    app: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      connectOutlets: function(router) {
        router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet({
          viewClass: App.HeaderView,
          outletName: 'header'
        });
      },
      index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
          router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet(...);
        }
      }),
      one: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/one',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
          // if you have a OneController and OneView:
          router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet('one');
        }
      }),
      ...
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: If you take a look at the console output, this jsfiddle shows the `applicationController` is not yet ready in the `connectOutlets` method of the root route: http://jsfiddle.net/SQp7x/14/

Comment: I heard about a trick to solve these kinds of glitches by just putting everything in a child route of root. http://jsfiddle.net/dmazza/SQp7x/15/