# How to set a controller property and update a template in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to show a TopController property in a TopView template. In TopView, I have `sectionBinding: 'controller.section'`.

From my understanding of Ember.js, in TopView, the `controller` property should refer to my TopController. **Yet it seems to refer to ApplicationController?** Read on:

In my router, I have `router.set('topController.section', 'index');`... But that doesn't seem to do anything in this case. Changing it to `router.set('applicationController.section', 'index');` **works** and the `{{section}}` part in the TopView template changes to "index".

I have created two fiddles showing my issue. The first one doesn't work:

FAULTY -> http://jsfiddle.net/8tQ4q/4/

The second one does work:

WORKS -> http://jsfiddle.net/8tQ4q/5/

The only difference is the `topController` / `applicationController` part in `router.set()`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're expecting `topController` to be connected to `TopView`. You haven't done anything to make this connection. I think you may be confused because `connectOutlet('top')` would create a `TopView` that is connected to `topController`. However, you aren't doing this anywhere in your app.

You also don't need the `sectionBinding`. If you have a `controller` defined on your view, it will be the default context.

Comment: +1, and I would complete by saying that the second example works simply because the topView's controller fallback to its parentView's controller, which is applicationController.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Peter. I'm sorry about the confusion. From my understanding based on what I've read so far, there should always be a connection between <name>Controller and <name>View (reflected in the 'controller' property per default) - which is not the case then.

It's my hope to be able to aid you in writing documentation onwards, but I feel a bit lost at this point (without having read the entire source code). :( Anyway, thanks again, I'll give it another go.

Comment: @Peter Wagenet, I found an example by pangratz here that seems to do the same as I'm attempting, yet it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628489/emberjs-how-to-mark-active-menu-item-using-router-infrastructure - Where exactly does pangratz make the connection between the NavigationController and the NavigationView?

Comment: Okay, never mind. I read most of the source and I get the concepts now. I don't know where I read about the naming part, but that's clearly wrong. Thanks Peter and @sly7_7 for your input, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
router.get('topController').set('section', 'index');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tQ4q/8/ - Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I can't help but think this is a bug of some sort?

Comment: `set` also takes a path. So `set('topController.section', 'index')` should behave the same as `get('topController').set('section', 'index')`.