# Ember.js mark active menu binding misunderstood

Tags: ember.js

I was trying to fully understand the previous answer of the question [emberjs - how to mark active menu item using router infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628489/emberjs-how-to-mark-active-menu-item-using-router-infrastructure)

In the answer I tried to simplify (without using a outlet navigation and without adding a second level routing under the root) but in my case the active link doesn't work ://

Here's a fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/archange/Scqxw/

What I don't understand in the fiddle is why the "isActive: function()" is not updated after the set on the router... :/

So if someone passing by can explain me the reason. Big Thanks.
And if someone has another solution for handling navigation menu (perhaps using bindAttr ?)

Thanks

Comment: Found a better solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412073/assigning-active-class-to-selected-list-item-in-emberjs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that when a template/view creates another view, it gives the newly created view access to it's controller. For example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{view App.NavigationView}}
</script>
```

The controller of the navigation view is going to be the instance `applicationController`. This is expected behavior.

If you want to tell your newly created `NavigationView` to use another controller, just pass that in, like so:

```
{{view App.NavigationView controllerBinding="navigationController"}}
```

Please note that I wired these two controllers together in `App.ready`.

Here is your edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Scqxw/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the fiddle, I don't understand the reason for coupling the 2 controllers (app and nav). When I delete this link, I got an error `Target <(subclass of Em.View)> doesnt have action gotoAllTeachers`. I read again the doc. And I dound 'Ember sets the controller variable on the context (...) If a view has no controller property, inherits the controller from most recent view with one." Perfect I undertand my first mistake. From doc 'The controller singletons'll have their target property set to the application's router singleton'. Can you elaborate about wiring the controllers ?