# Assigning 'active' class to selected list item in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a list and I'd like to set one item as class="active" automatically.  Given the following bootstrap code:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li {{bindAttr class="atIndex:active"}}>{{#linkTo "index"}}Index{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li {{bindAttr class="atAbout:active"}}>{{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li {{bindAttr class="atLogin:active"}}>{{#linkTo "login"}}Login{{/linkTo}}</li>
</ul>
```

atIndex, atAbout and atLogin reside in my ApplicationController.

To render as:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active"><a...>Index{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li><a...>About<a></li>
<li><a...>Login<a></li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way to do this with Ember 1.0 pre4?  I'd rather not add special code to every view or controller.

PS - `atIndex: true` works, but `atIndex: function() {return true; }.property().volatile()` does not. Which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li" href=false}}
  <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>
    Dashboard
  </a>
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Yes, if you add href=false to the linkto, this will actually generate valid HTML.  :-)

Comment: In HTML 4.01, the <a> tag could be either a hyperlink or an anchor. In HTML5, the <a> tag is always a hyperlink, but if it has no href attribute, it is only a placeholder for a hyperlink. @shs you can write without href and html will be valid.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, as linkTo doesn't change the view context anymore.

Comment: With Ember version v1.0.0-rc.1-13-gd3f0c73 it still works - just confirmed it on one of our projects.

Comment: Even though this is a pretty fine solution, it seems like it prevents navigation items to work on Mobile Safari - just did a quick test on an iPad2 (iOS 6.0) and an iPhone5 (6.0.1).

Comment: Here is a workaround: just repeat the link inside, you'll have the active class on li and the href in the anchor this way :
{{#linkTo "dashboard" tagName="li" href=false}}{{#linkTo "dashboard"}}Dashboard{{/linkTo}}{{/linkTo}}

I guess the best thing to do is write your own view, but in my case it's a purely static part, not worth it.

Comment: Nesting linkTo causes problems with the number of events fired when clicking on the link.
See a solution: http://dmathieu.com/articles/development/emberjs-twitter-bootstrap-active-li/

Comment: For newer versions of Ember, be sure to use `link-to` instead of `linkTo`.

Comment: Where does that `view` variable come from?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the latest build of ember and ended up going with what joelmoss suggests here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1849

Comment: Adapted for Ember `1.3.1` (and possibly fresher versions): 

`{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li" href=false}}<a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Dashboard</a>{{/link-to}}`

Comment: Where is the documentation that there exists a bind-attr `view.href`?  I can’t seem to find it.

Comment: Worked for me, not sure I understand the solution entirely but it did indeed work with latest version of ember-cli.

Comment: Current versions of Ember do not require the `href=false` parameter. The attribute will not be added if the tag to be generated is not 'a'. Tested with Ember 1.10.0
[Source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember/tests/helpers/link_to_test.js#L143)

Comment: This works and it makes absolutely no sense to me.  The `active` class is added appropriately, but I don't know why...  Using ember 1.11.1

Comment: Using Ember 2.11.0 here. It seems that bind-attr was removed. Using <a href={{view.href}}> works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

By far the cleanest way to solve this is by taking advantage of the `linkTo` helper's built-in support for setting the active class when rendering links. AFAIK this is not yet documented other than in the source code:

implementation: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L46

example: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember/tests/helpers/link_to_test.js#L120

To take advantage of this feature just adjust your css to style based on having an active class on the link instead of the `li` element. If you really need to style the `li` you can create a custom view and helper that extends `Ember.LinkView` and uses an `li` but changing css will be far easier.

--- UPDATE ----

Since we all love twitter bootstrap *just changing the css* is perhaps not such a great option. In that case, the following will do the trick:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    Ember.run.next( this, function() {
      this.$("ul.nav li:has(>a.active)").addClass('active');
      this.$("ul.nav li:not(:has(>a.active))").removeClass('active');
    });
  }.observes('controller.currentPath')
});
```

Working example using ember linkTo helper with bootstrap pills: http://jsbin.com/ekobod/5/edit (requires ember-1.0.0-pre.4)

Comment: Unfortunately for this problem I'm using the popular javascript-bootstrap controls in my project.  (Fortunately, though, because they're really great. :-)  It would be neat if the linkTo could somehow push a value into the controller automatically that in turn would bind to the <li>'s active class.

Comment: The closest I've found is this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328295/how-do-i-bind-to-the-active-class-of-a-link-using-the-new-ember-router

Comment: There is a new pull-request with solution for wrapping linkTo tag in an li, might want to have a look and comment https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1849

Comment: Neat stuff there.  I filed [this one](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1822) but it wasn't as popular.  Thanks!

Comment: This function `currentPathDidChange` is only run when the path-depth is changing. Not when the same level is changing: from `/pages/1` to `/pages/2`

Comment: Thanks Mike, your solution works Ok with nested navs with which I hade problems using Yehuda's solution from the link above

Comment: `this.$("ul.nav li:has(>a.active)").addClass('active');
      this.$("ul.nav li:not(:has(>a.active))").removeClass('active');`

is changing the class of the <a> tag.  How can I get it to change the class of the <li> tag to work with bootstrap?

Answer (score 5):

the active route's path is updated automatically in the `ApplicationController` via `currentPath` so I did something like that in my App...
In `ApplicationController` added properties like so:

```
isProductsActive: function(){
  if ( this.get('currentPath') === 'products' ) return 'active';
  else return '';
}.property('currentPath')
```

and in my `ApplicationView` template:

```
<li {{bindAttr class="isProductsActive"}}>
  {{#linkTo "products"}}Products{{/linkTo}}
</li>
```

Comment: This is a good idea.  But I'll be adding lots of <li> items and I'm looking for a more general purpose solution that I can apply to all of them without special casing each and every link.

Answer (score 5):

I made an ember-cli addon that handles this:

https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-cli-active-link-wrapper

Comment: This solution was the best for me.  Many of the nested link-to suggestions didn't either didn't show the link address anymore, or showed a regular cursor instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**:
Finally, the best way I've found to use the activate class of bootstrap li element using ember.js of the link.

```
{{#linkTo "dives" tagName="li"}}
   <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>Dives</a>
{{/linkTo}}
```

--------------8<--------------

**DEPRECATED:**

I guess the previous answers were relevant before Ember.js introduced the activeClass attribute for linkTo helper.
Now I would solve the problem like this :

```
<ul class="nav">
<li >{{#linkTo "index" activeClass="active"}}Index{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li >{{#linkTo "about" activeClass="active}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
<li >{{#linkTo "login" activeClass="active}}Login{{/linkTo}}</li>
</ul>
```

Enber will automatically add the class when relevant.

Comment: no, the question is about adding the active class to the _list item_, not the link.

Comment: yes I know, but it makes more sense using the already builtin helper in the _link_ rather than building complex logical to have the effect in the _list item_... except if OP wants to modify specific _list item_ DOM attribute.

Comment: @user11012 Thanks for your response - even though it might be not exactly answering the asked question, it is quite useful to know about it - I didn't and you saved me some time :)

Comment: @user11012, it doesn't make more sense when you're using a front-end framework like Bootstrap, which uses the "active" class on the li item, rather than the link itself.

Comment: Okay, here is the way to use the bootstrap feature with ember.js I've found :               `code {{#linkTo "dives" tagName="li"}}
                <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>Dives</a>
              {{/linkTo}}`

Answer (score 2):

If I may suggest another solution that requires nothing but Handlebars:

```
<li {{bind-attr class="view.innerLink.active:active"}}>
    {{#link-to "path" viewName="innerLink"}}Click{{/link-to}}
</li>
```

This sets the `LinkView` object as a member of the parent view, which's active attribute you can then reference.

Comment: As opposed to other solutions involving bind-attr and view.href this actually still works with Ember 1.12 and HTMLbars!!! You can use class={{view.innerLink.active}}.

Answer (score 2):

I found a pretty simple Solution using linked items in a list group(http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked).

```
<div class="list-group">
{{#each thing in list}}
    {{#link-to "details" thing.id tagName="a" href="view.href" class="list-group-item" {{thing.name}} {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Works with Bootstrap v3.1.1 and Ember v1.7.0

Answer (score 2):

Just nest the {{link-to}} with a tagName on the outer one. I'm doing this on EmberJS 2.0.

```
{{#link-to "admin.websocket" tagName="li"}}
    {{#link-to "admin.websocket"}}WebSocket{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Bootstrap navigation in Ember then you can use Bootstrap for Ember that has out of the box support for this:

Github: https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember
Demo: http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/#/show_components/tabs

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these answers are outdated. Here is a much cleaner (and DRY) version for Bootstrap and Ember 2.x:

```
{{#link-to "index" tagName="li" as |link|}}
  <a href="#" class="{{if link.active 'active'}}">Index Page</a>
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: This does not work. Seems `link` is undefined. WTF?!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by creating a view for each item and using `classNameBindings` (I have to say that i don't have a HTML list, i.e.`<a>...</a>` in my app, just  list of `<div>`).

Here is the way it works for me:

In tasklist.handlebars i iterate over my custom view

```
  {{#each tasks}}
    {{view App.TaskListItemView contentBinding="this"....}}
  {{/each}}
```

Ember will insert a view (i. e. `<div>`) for each item.

The view class for each item is defined in task_list_item_view.js as

```
App.TaskListItemView = Ember.View.extend({

  controller: null,
  classNameBindings: ['isSelected', 'isClosed'],

  isClosed: function() {
      var content = this.get('content');
      return content && !content.isOpen(new Date);
  }.property('controller.content.@each'),

  isSelected: function() {
      return (this.get('controller').isSelectedTask(this.get('content')));
  }.property('controller.taskSelection.@each'),

  ....
});
```

Finally the template for the view just renders my link in tasklistitem.handlebars

```
<a {{action "selectTask" view.content target="view"}} rel="tooltip"
         {{bindAttr title="view.content.comment"}} class="taskListLink">
  ....
</a>
```

AFAIK you have to specify the source data in the `property()` call to let ember know when to (re-) evaluate the property.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

I went with:

```
 Ember.LinkView.reopen({
didInsertElement:function(){

    if(this.$().hasClass('active')){

        this.$().parent().addClass('active');

    }
}
```

});

I didn't want to use the accepted answer as I wanted to keep my li elements as plain old html. There might be a better way to check the active state but I couldn't get access to the right property.

Comment: This will not work when you navigate around your app