# Create a <li class="active"> around an active {{linkTo}}

Tags: ember.js

What is the cleanest way to get `<li class="active">` for the active page in the following Ember app?

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>{{#linkTo 'ping'}}Ping{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo 'pong'}}Pong{{/linkTo}}</li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("ping", { path: "/ping" });
  this.route("pong", { path: "/pong" });
});
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14412073/923560

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace in your template the `li` tags like so:

index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <ul class="nav">
    {{#linkTo 'ping' tagName="li"}}Ping{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo 'pong' tagName="li"}}Pong{{/linkTo}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

the `{{linkTo}}` with the tagName specified will apply a css class name of 'active' automatically when the application's current route matches the supplied route name.

example, when your app url is at `/#/ping` the resulting markup would be something like:

```
 ...
 <li class="active">Ping</li>
 ...
```

**Or you create a custom view**

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function() {
    return this.get('childViews.firstObject.active');
  }.property()
});
```

and then use it like so

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <ul class="nav">
   {{#view App.ItemView}}
     {{#linkTo 'ping'}}Ping{{/linkTo}}
   {{/view}}
   {{#view App.ItemView}}
     {{#linkTo 'pong'}}Pong{{/linkTo}}
   {{/view}}
   </ul>
 </script>
```

some css to see it actually working

```
li a {
  color: #000; 
}
li a.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I was hoping to tackle this one with a "simple" `bindattr` within the `<li>` element. It seems to be an awful lot of code for such a simple thing.

Comment: The `tagName` property of the `{{#linkTo}}` is all you really need. Creating the custom view is not necessary.

Comment: @MehulKar I already mentioned this, thus the two options in my answer :) but you are right the first solution is the easier one

Comment: Yup :) I was just reiterating in response to @wintermeyer's comment.

Comment: @MehulKar The `tagName` doesn't help me. I need to have a `<a>` within the `<li>` and I need the `<li>` to be with a `class='active'`. Plus I can't change the CSS.

Comment: Ahh ok. Yeah, then you'll need to create a custom view as described in this answer.

Comment: This is insanely complicated to solve a VERY simple problem. Was hoping for something like this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active    #ember i guess....

Answer (score 12):

This workaround did it for me:

```
{{#linkTo  'menus.search' tagName='li' href=false}}
    {{#linkTo 'menus.search'}}
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/linkTo}}
```

It creates an li element containing an anchor element. And both will be updated with the "active" class when the route is active.

Answer (score 2):

Just nest the `{{link-to}}` with a `tagName` on the outer one. This will set an active class on both the outer `<li>` and the inner `<a>` tag.

```
{{#link-to "ping" tagName="li"}}
    {{#link-to "ping"}}ping{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}

{{#link-to "pong" tagName="li"}}
    {{#link-to "pong"}}pong{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```