# how to determine active child route in Ember 2?

Tags: ember.js

For example, say I have:

- a master-detail setup (a Widgets `route`, with a nested Widget route)
- in the master template I model, which is `Widget.all` to a component that lays it out as a list of `{{link-to}}` each of which transitions to the `widgets.widget` route

...then what is/are the recommended way(s) in ember 2 to tell that component what the selected widget is, so it can highlight its link?

Answer (score 0):

Ember's routing infrastructure automatically handles adding active classes to links provided you're using the link-to helper.

See [emberjs - how to mark active menu item using router infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628489/emberjs-how-to-mark-active-menu-item-using-router-infrastructure)

If you want to use a tag besides an anchor tag, like an li, see: [Create a <li class="active"> around an active {{linkTo}}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380523/create-a-li-class-active-around-an-active-linkto)

Comment: I need to be able to add the class to the li, and in any case, was primarily interested in the general case not the specific case. I do see however that you can write custom components that inherit from link-to, so that is a possibility for getting the active behaviour for free.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be specific to link to a li.