# How can I use data to construct a class name using the Ember #link-to helper?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember.js and creating a link to a route using the `#link-to` helper. I'd like to use some data to construct a class name. Is that possible? If so, how can I do that?

```
{{#link-to 'model' model.property class="myclass--model.property"}}
    {{model.property}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Of course, with this code `class="myclass--model.property"` will compile as a string. Is there any way to escape the string? Or is there a different approach I should be using?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14501015/382809 and use `{{bind-attr class="foo"}}` on the `a` tag if you don't find a proper solution ( i'm no ember user yet )

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to to something like this:

```
{{#link-to 'model' model.property class=model.property}}
    {{model.property}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Take a look at [this](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xiliqote/7#/foos) working JSBin example.