# How do I bind to the active class of a link using the new Ember router?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for navigation in my Ember.js app. Bootstrap uses an `active` class on the `li` tag that wraps navigation links, rather than setting the `active` class on the link itself.

Ember.js's new `linkTo` helper will set an `active` class on the link but (as far as I can see) doesn't offer any to hook on to that property.

Right now, I'm using this ugly approach:

```
{{#linkTo "inbox" tagName="li"}}
  <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>Inbox</a>
{{/linkTo}}
```

This will output:

```
<li class="active" href="/inbox"><a href="/inbox">Inbox</a></li>
```

Which is what I want, but is not valid HTML.

I also tried binding to the generated LinkView's `active` property from the parent view, but if you do that, the parent view will be rendered twice before it is inserted which triggers an error.

Apart from manually recreating the logic used internally by the `linkTo` helper to assign the `active` class to the link, is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Due to a recent change this doesn't even work anymore (as the linkTo helper doesn't set the view context to its view anymore).

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, I found these answers to be more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628489/emberjs-how-to-mark-active-menu-item-using-router-infrastructure

Comment: Found a better solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412073/assigning-active-class-to-selected-list-item-in-emberjs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use nested link-to's:

```
{{#link-to "ccprPracticeSession.info" controller.controllers.ccprPatient.content content tagName='li' href=false eventName='dummy'}}
  {{#link-to "ccprPracticeSession.info" controller.controllers.ccprPatient.content content}}Info{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Notice that sine ember v1.0.0-rc.3 the href defaults to false if tagName !== 'a' ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1849))

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one because this is how I do this now, and updated the answer to remove the href=false

Comment: This isn't much prettier

Answer (score 27):

We definitely need a more public, permanent solution, but something like this should work for now.

The template:

```
<ul>
{{#view App.NavView}}
  {{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}
{{/view}}

{{#view App.NavView}}
  {{#linkTo "contacts"}}Contacts{{/linkTo}}
{{/view}}
</ul>
```

The view definition:

```
App.NavView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function() {
    return this.get('childViews.firstObject.active');
  }.property()
});
```

This relies on a couple of constraints:

- The nav view contains a single, static child view
- You are able to use a view for your `<li>`s. There's a lot of detail [in the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/) about how to customize a view's element from its JavaScript definition or from Handlebars.

I have supplied [a live JSBin](http://jsbin.com/olovun/2/edit) of this working.

Comment: Is there any reason this wouldn't work with a CollectionView's itemViewClass? It looks to me like the instance of itemViewClass doesn't have any childViews.

Comment: @YehudaKatz nice solution, I just found this after answering a related question. Figured I'd add comment here since my approach could help anyone stuck by one of the constraints you mentioned. Totally agreed something more public/permanent is needed, will give that some thought.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412073/assigning-active-class-to-selected-list-item-in-emberjs/14416595#14416595

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?) - it triggers a "you tried to re-render the view after it was rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM" error. My hack-ish solution still works.

Comment: In the demo, the `li` doesn't get the `active` class when clicked. It's just the underlying anchor being changed by the default `linkTo` behaviour. Also, the `App.NavView.active` property doesn't have `childViews.firstObject.active` as a dependency so I don't get how it's supposed to update anyway.

Comment: It seems as if the child linkTo view is not yet rendered(created?) when the active-property is evaluated (triggered by the classNameBinding?). Hence the childViews array is empty. I added `.property("childViews.@each")` which triggered it to be re-evaluated when the childViews changed. This however causes the error @Nick Ragaz is describing in the comment above. (full disclosure, i'm just learning ember)

Comment: Let's make that `property("childViews.@each.active")` in my comment above.

Comment: Adding 'childViews.firstObject.active' to the property() call in Yehuda's jsbin fixed it for me. Here it is working: http://jsbin.com/apisic/1/edit

Comment: The use of `viewName` on the `linkTo`/`link-to` wouldn't make the first constraint go away?

Answer (score 9):

Well I took what @alexspeller great idea and converted it to ember-cli:

app/components/link-li.js

```
export default Em.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['active'],
    active: function() {
        return this.get('childViews').anyBy('active');
    }.property('childViews.@each.active')
});
```

In my navbar I have:

```
{{#link-li}}
    {{#link-to "squares.index"}}Squares{{/link-to}}
{{/link-li}}
{{#link-li}}
    {{#link-to "games.index"}}Games{{/link-to}}
{{/link-li}}
{{#link-li}}
    {{#link-to "about"}}About{{/link-to}}
{{/link-li}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out how to do this with ember-cli

Comment: Good luck with `childViews` in Glimmer era.

Answer (score 6):

Building on katz' answer, you can have the `active` property be recomputed when the nav element's `parentView` is clicked.

```
App.NavView = Em.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: 'active'.w(),

    didInsertElement: function () {
        this._super();
        var _this = this;
        this.get('parentView').on('click', function () {
            _this.notifyPropertyChange('active');
        });
    },

    active: function () {
        return this.get('childViews.firstObject.active');
    }.property()
});
```

Comment: This is a good start, but when you refresh the page, the active class is gone.

Comment: When you also set `this.notifyPropertyChange('active');` under `this._super()' the problem with refreshing is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I have just written a component to make this a bit nicer:

```
App.LinkLiComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],
  active: function() {
    return this.get('childViews').anyBy('active');
  }.property('childViews.@each.active')
});

Em.Handlebars.helper('link-li', App.LinkLiComponent);
```

Usage:

```
{{#link-li}}
  {{#link-to "someRoute"}}Click Me{{/link-to}}
{{/link-li}}
```

Comment: could you explain how this works? I have an open question regarding it

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the logic used internally.  The other methods seemed more hackish.  This will also make it easier to reuse the logic elsewhere I might not need routing.

Used like this.

```
{{#view App.LinkView route="app.route" content="item"}}{{item.name}}{{/view}}

App.LinkView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['active'],
    active: Ember.computed(function() {
      var router = this.get('router'),
      route = this.get('route'),
      model = this.get('content');
      params = [route];

      if(model){
        params.push(model);
      }

      return router.isActive.apply(router, params);
    }).property('router.url'),
    router: Ember.computed(function() {
      return this.get('controller').container.lookup('router:main');
    }),
    click: function(){
        var router = this.get('router'),
        route = this.get('route'),
        model = this.get('content');
        params = [route];

        if(model){
            params.push(model);
        }

        router.transitionTo.apply(router,params);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've accepted this because it is probably the best way to go about it - the other answers all broke with new Ember.js updates. However, the easiest and most reliable thing to do in my case was to patch bootstrap so that an active class on the `a` tag has the same effect as an active class on the `li`.

Comment: Which can be done by adding the following after line `4634` in `bootstrap.css` (version 2.3.2):  `.navbar .nav a.active,
.navbar .nav a.active:hover,
.navbar .nav a.active:focus`

Comment: This solution ends up not using an A tag which breaks the usual link functionality in browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can skip extending a view and use the following.

```
{{#linkTo "index" tagName="li"}}<a>Homes</a>{{/linkTo}}
```

Even without a href Ember.JS will still know how to hook on to the LI elements.

Comment: This solution leaves the link without a HREF which breaks usual browser interactions (right click to open in new window, copy url etc)

Answer (score 1):

Current answers at time of writing are dated. In later versions of Ember if you are using `{{link-to}}` it automatically sets `'active'` class on the `<a>` element when the current route matches the target link.

So just write your css with the expectation that the `<a>` will have `active` and it should do this out of the box.

Lucky that feature is added. All of the stuff here which was required to solve this "problem" prior is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: The question is about elements other than <a> - that behaviour was present before.

Comment: Why don't you wrap the li in {{link-to}} then you can use this feature and select with "a.active li" ? it's not valid html but it tends to work anyway. Better though is to use <nav><a>...<a><nav> and get rid of the li problem altogether. this is an issue for anyone who uses UL / OL for navigation, which is pretty common . The NAV aproach is designed specifically to address that in HTML5 http://blog.echoenduring.com/2011/02/23/how-html5-changes-the-way-we-think-of-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

For the same problem here I came with jQuery based solution not sure about performance penalties but it is working out of the box. I reopen Ember.LinkView and extended it.

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var el = this.$();

        if(el.hasClass('active')){
            el.parent().addClass('active');
        }

        el.click(function(e){
            el.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```