# How to set active menubar item in ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have an ember application with a bootstrap menubar. By default the home button is rendered as being the active option and is blue. How do I change the active option based on what link is selected?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="max-width: 300px;">
      <li class="active">
      <a href="#"{{#link-to "index"}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> &nbsp &nbsp Home {{/link-to}}</a>
      </li>    
      <li>
      <a href="#"{{#link-to "settings"}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> &nbsp &nbsp Settings {{/link-to}}</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>  Logout</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: According to http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ the `link-to` helper is supposed to take care of this automatically

EDIT: I have tried experimenting with the following-

```
<ul class="nav">
    {{#linkTo 'index' tagName="li"}}Home{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo 'settings' tagName="li"}}Settings{{/linkTo}}
  </ul>
```

because according to the ember page link above, the tagName attribute is responsible for assigning the active class, but it doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link-to` by default creates an `<a>` element, and set the class `active` when the current route matches the target route of the link. The bootstrap expects the `active` class to be present in the `li` tag. And an `<a>` element inside.

So you need to use `{{#link-to ... tagName="li"}}` like your second aproach and inside an `<a>` element. Otherwise the style isn't applied.

Like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="max-width: 300px;">
  {{#link-to "index" tagName="li"}}
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> &nbsp &nbsp Home</a>
  {{/link-to}}      
  {{#link-to "settings" tagName="li"}}
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> &nbsp &nbsp Settings</a>
  {{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to "logout" tagName="li"}}
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>  Logout</a>
  {{/link-to}}
</ul>
```

See this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/E63Hy/

The only downside of this, is your href won't match the target route, it's fixed with `href="#"`. Because when the `link-to` tagName is different of `a`, no href is generated. So even a `<a href="{{href}}">` doesn't work. Of course, this is just visual, clicking in the link-to will transition to the target route, and update the url accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is actually simple.
Just wrap your usual link-to with another link-to with tagName="li".

```
<ul class="nav">
    {{#link-to 'index' tagName="li"}}
        {{#link-to 'index'}}
            Home
        {{/link-to}}
    {{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'settings' tagName="li"}}
        {{#link-to 'settings'}}
            Settings
        {{/link-to}}
    {{/link-to}}
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a better solution than nesting an anchor tag because when opening the link in a new tab it maintains the URL.

Answer (score 1):

actually see yehuda's answer,

[How do I bind to the active class of a link using the new Ember router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328295/how-do-i-bind-to-the-active-class-of-a-link-using-the-new-ember-router)

Comment: That doesnt produce a link!

Answer (score 1):

I have just written a component to make this a bit nicer:

```
App.LinkLiComponent = Em.Component.extend
  tagName:            'li'
  classNameBindings:  ['active']
  active:             (->
    @get('childViews').anyBy 'active'
  ).property 'childViews.@each.active'

Em.Handlebars.helper 'link-li', App.LinkLiComponent
```

Usage:

```
{{#link-li}}
  {{#link-to "someRoute"}}Click Me{{/link-to}}
{{/link-li}}
```