# Nested routes in Ember.js router and initialState

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm trying to understand emeber.js routing. I'm not really sure, why this is not valid definition of router

```
Platby.Router = Ember.Router.extend   
  location: 'hash'   
  enableLogging : true

  root: Ember.Route.extend
    index: Ember.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      initialState: 'batches'
      enter: (router) -> console.log 'root.index'

      batches: Ember.Route.extend
        initialState: 'index'
        route: '/batches'
        enter: (router) -> console.log 'root.index.batches'

        index: Ember.Route.extend
          route: '/'
          enter: (router) -> console.log 'root.index.batches.index'
```

Once proceed to the root url, I get the following output in the console.

```
STATEMANAGER: Entering root
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'navigateAway' to state root.
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'unroutePath' to state root. 
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'routePath' to state root. 
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Could not find state for path
```

Will be somebody able to explain me, where's the problem?

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't see you calling `connectOutlets`. There are a few other questions about the Router at StackOverflow you could take a look at... You might wanna look into [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318572/right-way-to-do-navigation-with-ember/11319609#11319609) for example, as well as [**this guide**](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/).

Comment: This code is only snippet, to show the idea. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only answer based on the information you've given... Regarding the error `uncaught Error: assertion failed: Could not find state for path`, this is because you have no leaf state that matches the path "/".

`root.index` matches '/' but it isn't a leaf, it has a single child state `batches` so the router will look in the children of `root.index` for a match for '/' and it doesn't find one, it only finds `batches` (which matches `'/batches'`) and the error is thrown. There has to be a leaf matching the route path.

As for helping with what you're actually trying to do, it looks like you want "/" to redirect to "/batches"? If that's the case:

```
Platby.Router = Em.Router.extend
  root: Em.Route.extend
    index: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      redirectsTo: 'batches'
    batches: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/batches'
      connectOutlets: ...
```

You can use `redirectsTo` as above, which is a shortcut for:

```
Platby.Router = Em.Router.extend
  root: Em.Route.extend
    index: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      connectOutlets: (router) ->
        router.transitionTo('batches')
    batches: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/batches'
      connectOutlets: ...
```

You can't use `redirectsTo` and have your own `connectOutlets` however, so if you need to do anything in `root.index` before transitioning to `root.batches` you will want to use the second way and handle your business before the `transitionTo`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what it is you want to do, but by the looks of it you want `/batches/` to route to `root.index.batches.index` and `/batches` to route to `root.index.batches`. Is that correct?

My understanding is that your `root.index.batches` and `root.index.batches.index` routes are actually the same route. If you remove the latter you should be good.